# C# - Unable to return correct value to int function using for/if combination

Tags: c#, list, return

I have a function that simply needs to return the index of the image currently displayed in a picturebox in the `List<Bitmap>` called `images`.
It is an `int` function called `displayImageIndex()`, and I originally tried to run it like this:

```
public int displayImageIndex()
{
    //index to return to function
    int displayIndex = 0;

    //access all images in list
    for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Count; ++i)
    {
        //matches image in picturebox
        if (picboxImage.ImageLocation == imagePaths[i])
        {
            //get index of image
            displayIndex = imagePaths.IndexOf(imagePaths[i]);
        }
    }

    return displayIndex;
}
```

This compiled but always returned displayIndex as 0, although the image was obviously being found as the rest of the program was working. I then tried like this:

```
public int displayImageIndex()
{
    //value to return to function
    int displayIndex;

    //access all images in list
    for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Count; ++i)
    {
        //matches image in picturebox
        if (picboxImage.ImageLocation == imagePaths[i])
        {
            //get index of image
            displayIndex = imagePaths.IndexOf(imagePaths[i]);
            return displayIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error that tells me 'not all code paths return a value'. I tried to fix this by adding an `else` to the `if` statement, but this gave me a warning that the loop may contain unreachable code.

Basically, however I try to run it I get an error of some sort.
I don't know what to do because the function is absolutely always going to find a value (the image on the picbox will always be one from the `images` list), I just need an efficient way that will always return this value, but I can't figure out how to put it into the function.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be awesome, thankyou in advance!

Mark

Comment: Some question. Why are you using preincrement `++i`? Why are you using function `indexof`? Wont `i` be your index?

Comment: Are you sure the ImageLocation exists in imagePaths? Maybe the images are moved? Also, why are you using IndexOf? Isn't 'i' good enough?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know that your code should always return something, and "thinks" that the if could be never hit, in this case the method would return nothing. You can fix this by e. g. throwing an excepttion if nothing is found, like this:

```
for(...)
{
    //...
}
throw new Exception("The item you searched for isn't on the list!");
```

I am not quite sure why you use a method to get an index for something you already know, I think you can replace this line

```
displayIndex = imagePaths.IndexOf(imagePaths[i]);
```

by this one:

```
displayIndex = i;
```

Then, your whole function should have the same functionality as IndexOf itself, so your entire code should shrink down to something like this:

```
return imagePaths.IndexOf(picboxImage.ImageLocation);
```

I guess your error is that picboxImage.ImageLocation is not actually contained in your list. Maybe it is formatted wrong. You should try setting a breakpoint and investigating the contents of the variables by hovering your mouse cursor over them. This is a very easy way to find out what their exact content is.

Comment: Just a note, `IndexOutOfRangeException` in this case doesn't make any sense

Comment: @codroipo More than that, using it here is risky since trying to catch `IndexOutOfRangeException` in the exception window will also catch this one and can make a debugging nightmare.

Comment: You're right, throwing another type of exception would be better. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ***the image was obviously not found*** otherwise `displayIndex` would have changed, so you will have to debug it and see if `imagePaths` really contains `picboxImage.ImageLocation`.

- Put a breakpoint in the method.
- Use F11 to step into.
- Inspect `imagePaths` in the *watch window* to see if your picture is there.
- Also note that ***`string` comparison is case sensitive*** so you either want to use `imagePaths[i].ToLower == picboxImage.ImageLocation.ToLower()` or `picboxImage.ImageLocation.Equals(imagePaths[i], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);`.

Also, you should just use

```
displayIndex = i;
```

Instead of:

```
displayIndex = imagePaths.IndexOf(imagePaths[i]);
```

***You already have the index!***

For the *not all code paths return a value* you need to make sure that there is a `return` statement event if no image was found. just add a default `return` value in the end of the method like this:

```
public int displayImageIndex()
{
    //access all images in list
    for (int i = 0; i < imagePaths.Count; ++i)
    {
        //matches image in picturebox
        if (picboxImage.ImageLocation == imagePaths[i])
        {
            //get index of image
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Or simplify it to the following Linq statement:

```
public int displayImageIndex()
{
    return imagePaths.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(picboxImage.ImageLocation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IndexOf` and `ToLower()` to find item this way:

```
public int DisplayImageIndex()
{
    return imagePaths.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList()
                     .IndexOf(picboxImage.ImageLocation.ToLower());
}
```

The function returns -1 if imagePaths doesn't contain that path.

Comment: What happens if the OP has a list with 100,000 images. Would you want to allocate a lowercase string for each of them? This won't scale well.

Comment: If OP has a list of 100 000 or 1 000 000 or 10 000 000 images, he shouldn't be using this approach anyway, but instead save the selected index or use a Dictionary to save the path-index relation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov When coming out from home,  you don't wear a helmet by default. But if you want to ride a motorcycle, yes you should wear one;)

Comment: @RezaAghaei You take into account that the OP either knows this, or he's has a small array size. Both of these are assumptions. You should at least tell the OP that this has significant overhead if he ever attempts to scale.

Comment: @georch You're probably right. But someone who isn't aware of that fact, and perhaps is a beginner, make take this as a recommendation for cases which aren't suitable.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think when the user is using a `for` loop, the answer is good fit, and we don't need to describe about rare situations and exceptional ones like having thousands of images, specially when such case is not mentioned in question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov probably we can say, don't write such function parameterless, don't refer to imagePaths and pictiureBox that way because they are not in scope of your function, pass imageLocation to function, don't use camel case for naming and ... But these are not main target of asking such question. Maybe better to comment about such things or write a side note :)

Comment: @georch **But instead save the selected index or use a Dictionary to save the path-index relation.** it's completely a different story, specially when we don't know how the ImageLocation has been set.